# Symfony 3.4 Website returns 404 on js and css resources

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-404

I have no experience with Symfony and my PHP is very rusty (last time I worked with it was at version 4).

I would like to host a copy of this website: https://thronesdb.com/
It has a public git repository located here: https://github.com/ThronesDB/thronesdb/

After following the instructions of README.md and making some minor adjustments to the location of the `web` folder I got it to kinda work: https://ccgdb.uber.space/

**Not sure if relevant:**
Due to limitations imposed by my hosting provider I was not able to use `Options +FollowSymLinks` in .htaccess but instead resorted to `Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch`.
Additionally, since Apache seems to be configured to not allow access in any folder except /var/www/virtual/ccgdb/html (which is my document root), I moved the whole folder I got when checking out above mentioned repository in /var/www/virtual/ccgdb/html/ccgdb and copied all files from /var/www/virtual/ccgdb/html/ccgdb/web to /var/www/virtual/ccgdb/html.

The website itself loads and functions perfectly fine. But most of the resources (.css and .js files) return 404s. I have no idea where to look next.

**Any hints or ideas how to resolve those 404s?**

---

Content of .htaccess:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
#Options +FollowSymLinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

folder structure under /var/www/virtual/ccgdb/html:

```
[user@server html]$ tree -L 3
.
├── app_dev.php
├── app.php
├── bundles
│   ├── app -> ../ccgdb/src/AppBundle/Resources/public
│   ├── bazingajstranslation -> ../ccgdb/vendor/willdurand/js-translation-bundle/Resources/public
│   ├── fosjsrouting -> ../ccgdb/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public
│   └── nelmioapidoc -> ../ccgdb/vendor/nelmio/api-doc-bundle/Nelmio/ApiDocBundle/Resources/public
├── ccgdb (this is the git repository from https://github.com/ThronesDB/thronesdb/)
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── AppCache.php
│   │   ├── AppKernel.php
│   │   ├── config
│   │   └── Resources
│   ├── behat.yml.dist
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── console
│   │   └── symfony_requirements
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── config
│   │   └── dataimport
│   ├── features
│   │   ├── cards.feature
│   │   ├── Context
│   │   ├── Json
│   │   └── json_schema
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── phpcs.xml.dist
│   ├── phpunit.xml.dist
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── AppBundle
│   │   └── Migrations
│   ├── tests
│   │   └── AppBundle
│   ├── var
│   │   ├── bootstrap.php.cache
│   │   ├── cache
│   │   ├── logs
│   │   ├── sessions
│   │   └── SymfonyRequirements.php
│   ├── vendor
│   │   ├── autoload.php
│   │   ├── beberlei
│   │   ├── behat
│   │   ├── bin
│   │   ├── composer
│   │   ├── container-interop
│   │   ├── doctrine
│   │   ├── erusev
│   │   ├── ezyang
│   │   ├── fig
│   │   ├── friendsofsymfony
│   │   ├── gedmo
│   │   ├── guzzlehttp
│   │   ├── hamcrest
│   │   ├── incenteev
│   │   ├── jdorn
│   │   ├── jms
│   │   ├── justinrainbow
│   │   ├── kriswallsmith
│   │   ├── leafo
│   │   ├── michelf
│   │   ├── mockery
│   │   ├── monolog
│   │   ├── myclabs
│   │   ├── nelmio
│   │   ├── ocramius
│   │   ├── paragonie
│   │   ├── patchwork
│   │   ├── phar-io
│   │   ├── phpdocumentor
│   │   ├── phpspec
│   │   ├── phpunit
│   │   ├── psr
│   │   ├── ralouphie
│   │   ├── ramsey
│   │   ├── sebastian
│   │   ├── sensio
│   │   ├── sensiolabs
│   │   ├── squizlabs
│   │   ├── stof
│   │   ├── swiftmailer
│   │   ├── symfony
│   │   ├── theseer
│   │   ├── twig
│   │   ├── webmozart
│   │   ├── willdurand
│   │   └── zendframework
│   └── web
│       ├── app_dev.php
│       ├── app.php
│       ├── bundles
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── icon-120.png
│       ├── icon-192.png
│       └── robots.txt
├── favicon.ico
├── icon-120.png
├── icon-192.png
└── robots.txt

75 directories, 28 files
```

Comment: Probably the relative path of the css- & js-files is wrong. Could you post the directory structure under `/var/www/virtual/ccgdb/html` and maybe the content of the `.htaccess`?

Comment: original post extended

Comment: For now, I manually copied the missing .css and .js files from thronesdb.com. I would still be interested what I am doing wrong that those files weren't created for me. I you want me to remove my files again to investigate let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I changed the original web-root from `web` to `html` I followed these instructions: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory

Except I didn't follow the last step regarding the `AsseticBundle`. After doing that as well, everything is working now.

Note to self: RTFM